# How to focus on DropdownButtonFormField in flutter using FocusNode()?

Tags: flutter

I would like to focus on a [DropdownButtonFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButtonFormField-class.html) from a TextFormField in [Form](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Form-class.html) using `FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus()` or `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_myNextNode)`.

The problem is that DropdownButtonFormField does not provide `focusNode` attribute.

I saw that `focusNode` is available in [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) yet.

**SampleApp code :**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ListeTile Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() {
    return HomeScreenState();
  }
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String dropdownValue = 'One';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                onFieldSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
              ),
              DropdownButtonFormField(
                value: dropdownValue,
                items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
                    .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (String newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    dropdownValue = newValue;
                  });
                },
              )
            ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Although `DropdownButtonFormField` widget doesn't have `focusNode` property, you can wrap this widget with `Focus` and a `Listener` to achieve the desired result. Sample working code below:

```
FocusNode _node = new FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    onFieldSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
                  ),
                  Focus(
                      focusNode: _node,
                      onFocusChange: (bool focus) {
                        setState((){});
                      },
                      child: Listener(
                          onPointerDown: (_) {
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_node);
                          },
                          child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                            value: dropdownValue,
                            items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
                                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: value,
                                child: Text(value),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                            onChanged: (String newValue) {
                              setState(() {
                                dropdownValue = newValue;
                              });
                            },
                            iconSize: 50,
                            style: TextStyle(color: _node.hasFocus ? Colors.black : Colors.white70, fontSize: 24),

                            hint: Text('Select',
                              style: TextStyle(color: _node.hasFocus ? Colors.white : Colors.white70),
                            ),

                          )

                      )
                  )]))));
```

This results in : when you enter some text in `textfield` and hit tab then it shifts the focuses on first item in the `dropdownbuttonformfield`. Then you can navigate through other items in it using keyboard's tab key. Hitting enter on the highlighted item will make that item selected in the dropdown.

[image]

This solution is derived from [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42646#issuecomment-541682477) discussion.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank youn @Darshan  for your answer. I tried your proposition which help a little and allow me to discover `Focus()` but is sounds like a trade-off. The thing is that it would be fine that it opens the menu items on focused. This issue may be related to this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529394/how-to-open-dropdownbutton-when-other-widget-is-tapped-in-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529394/how-to-open-dropdownbutton-when-other-widget-is-tapped-in-flutter). As written, it seems to not have an easy issue without modifying the SDK.

Comment: DropdownButton has a focus node at this point in time.