# flutter unable to select dropdown value using the a container onTap

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to use a container to select a dropdown menu by wrapping the dropdown button with a container and then use a Gesture Detector. but i am getting an error

> The argument type 'void Function(String?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'

but if i make use of the unchange function on the dropdown menu its working fine

```
 GestureDetector(

      onTap: (String? newValue){
        setState(() {
                dropdowntargetGroupValue = newValue!;
              });
                      },
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton(
                value: dropdowntargetGroupValue,
                icon: Visibility(
                    visible: false, child: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward)),
                items: targetGroup.map((String items) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: items, child: Text(items));
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    dropdowntargetGroupValue = newValue!;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
    ),
```

Comment: In a second line of code "onTap: (String? newValue)". onTap of GestureDetector is not accept any parameter. I think you conflict with onChanged in DropdownButtonHideUnderline widget.

Comment: The GestureDectectors function signature is `void Function()`. In contrast to the `onChanged` callback of the DropdownButton the GestureDetector cannot know which value was selected. What are you trying to achieve by wrapping your DropdownButton in a GestureDetector in the first place?

Comment: Thank you, I want to be able to tap on the parent container to select from the dropdown instead of using the dropdown arrow button

Comment: Okay, looks like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529394/how-to-open-dropdownbutton-when-other-widget-is-tapped-in-flutter) could be helpful in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I will check it out now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `onChanged` callback in `onTap`.

I don't know what you're trying to do by wrapping `DropdownButton` with `GestureDetector` here but to make the `DropdownButton` open when another widget is tapped you've to make custom `DropdownButton` or use existing one. If you trying to do something when the `DropdownButton` is tapped, `DropdownButton` has it's own `onTap` property, you can use it.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed. What wanted to do is to select the dropdown options once I tap/click on the container to parent the dropdown button. If that is achievable

Comment: You've to use Custom DropdownButton, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529394/how-to-open-dropdownbutton-when-other-widget-is-tapped-in-flutter)

Comment: thanks man. im grateful.