# How to open DropDownButton on init page

Tags: flutter

i want to make a function for init `openDropDown();` when page loaded or tap on other widget

I found this in [stackoverfow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529394/how-to-open-dropdownbutton-when-other-widget-is-tapped-in-flutter)

but its not working maybe its outdated. how can i achieve. with flutter 2.10
here is my dropdown

```
DropdownButton(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    value: selectedValue,
                    items: [
                      for (var i = 0; i < this.clients.length; i++)
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(this.clients[i]['name'].toString() +
                                ' (' +
                                this.clients[i]['wallet'].toString() +
                                ') '),
                            value: this.clients[i]['id'].toString())
                    ],
                    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedValue = newValue!;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `GlobalKey` to get this job done... Also use `SchedulerBinding`  because in initState key would be null so you won't be able to open `DropDown` from `null key`... here is the proper code how you do that task

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter DropDownButton',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey _dropdownButtonKey = GlobalKey();
  final Intent _intent = const ActivateIntent();

// Initial Selected Value
  String dropdownvalue = 'Item 1';

// List of items in our dropdown menu
  var items = [
    'Item 1',
    'Item 2',
    'Item 3',
    'Item 4',
    'Item 5',
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (_dropdownButtonKey.currentContext != null) {
        _dropdownButtonKey.currentContext?.visitChildElements((element) {
          if (element.widget is Semantics) {
            element.visitChildElements((element) {
              if (element.widget is Actions) {
                element.visitChildElements((element) {
                  Actions.invoke(element, _intent);
                  return;
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            DropdownButton(
              autofocus: true,
              key: _dropdownButtonKey,
              isDense: true,
              isExpanded: true,
              value: dropdownvalue,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
              items: items.map((String items) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: items,
                  child: Text(items),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownvalue = newValue!;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```